# Left adjoint to direct sum?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory, modules

In the category of vector spaces, is there some endofunctor $F$ satisfying $$\mathrm{Hom}_k(M,\underset{i \in I}{\bigoplus} k) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_k(F(M),k)$$ for *every* $k$-vector space $M$?

Comment: Don't you want $\hom(M,\oplus_i N) \cong \hom(F(M),N)$, natural in $M,N$? Because then the title would fit to the question (and  also I can answer it :-)).

Comment: Hey again Martin :P
Um ya thts what I was looking for.. however I am doubting it exists... since $\bigoplus_i$ doesn't commute with products.. so it can't preserve limits... (failing SAFT)

Comment: Yes, exactly (but of course we only need the trivial direction of SAFT). So you are really interested in restricting to $N=k$?

Comment: Yup, since I was assuming that if all my modules are free (so in particular vector spaces) I would be able to treat them all as direct sums of k, and direct sums commute with each other.. so I would loose no generality in assuming N =k (using a little flip, flop argument).

Comment: This is not correct, since $\hom(M,-)$ doesn't commute with direct sums! The question for general $N$ does *not* reduce to $N=k$.

Comment: oops, sorry I don't know how I made that mistake...thats why I was toying with the idea of a left adjoint to direct products.. but I needed then to commute with direct sums to make it work (which they dont :/ )

Comment: If $I$ is fixed, $\bigoplus_{i\in I}k$ can be regarded just as any fixed vector space $X$. So, what you are looking for is $$\hom_k(M,X)\cong F(M)^*$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $M = k$ and let $I$ be countable. Then the LHS has countable dimension, but the RHS is a dual vector space, and dual vector spaces can only have finite or uncountable dimension.

Comment: I had also observed the same, and tried to use GCH for general infinite $I$.